# The model is broken when I replaced keras with tf.keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

When I tried to use keras to build a simple autoencoder, I found something strange between keras and tf.keras.

```
tf.__version__
```

2.2.0

```
(x_train,_), (x_test,_) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.  
x_train = x_train.reshape((len(x_train), 784))  
x_test = x_test.reshape((len(x_test), 784))  # None, 784
```

The original picture

```
plt.imshow(x_train[0].reshape(28, 28), cmap='gray')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8xc0.png)

```
import keras
# import tensorflow.keras as keras

my_autoencoder = keras.models.Sequential([
      keras.layers.Dense(64, input_shape=(784, ), activation='relu'),
      keras.layers.Dense(784, activation='sigmoid')                                             
])
my_autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')

my_autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs=10, shuffle=True, validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
```

training

```
Train on 60000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 7s 112us/step - loss: 0.2233 - val_loss: 0.1670
Epoch 2/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 7s 111us/step - loss: 0.1498 - val_loss: 0.1337
Epoch 3/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 7s 110us/step - loss: 0.1254 - val_loss: 0.1152
Epoch 4/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 7s 110us/step - loss: 0.1103 - val_loss: 0.1032
Epoch 5/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 7s 110us/step - loss: 0.1010 - val_loss: 0.0963
Epoch 6/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 7s 109us/step - loss: 0.0954 - val_loss: 0.0919
Epoch 7/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 7s 109us/step - loss: 0.0917 - val_loss: 0.0889
Epoch 8/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 7s 110us/step - loss: 0.0890 - val_loss: 0.0866
Epoch 9/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 7s 110us/step - loss: 0.0870 - val_loss: 0.0850
Epoch 10/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 7s 109us/step - loss: 0.0853 - val_loss: 0.0835
```

the decoded image with keras

```
temp = my_autoencoder.predict(x_train)

plt.imshow(temp[0].reshape(28, 28), cmap='gray')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUR8Q.png)

So far, everything is as normal as expected, but something is weird when I replaced keras with tf.keras

```
# import keras
import tensorflow.keras as keras
my_autoencoder = keras.models.Sequential([
      keras.layers.Dense(64, input_shape=(784, ), activation='relu'),
      keras.layers.Dense(784, activation='sigmoid')                                             
])
my_autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')

my_autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs=10, shuffle=True, validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
```

training

```
Epoch 1/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 5s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6952 - val_loss: 0.6940
Epoch 2/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 5s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6929 - val_loss: 0.6918
Epoch 3/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 5s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6907 - val_loss: 0.6896
Epoch 4/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 5s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6885 - val_loss: 0.6873
Epoch 5/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 5s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6862 - val_loss: 0.6848
Epoch 6/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 5s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6835 - val_loss: 0.6818
Epoch 7/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 5s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6802 - val_loss: 0.6782
Epoch 8/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 5s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6763 - val_loss: 0.6737
Epoch 9/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 5s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6714 - val_loss: 0.6682
Epoch 10/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 5s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6652 - val_loss: 0.6612
```

the decoded image with tf.keras

```
temp = my_autoencoder.predict(x_train)

plt.imshow(temp[0].reshape(28, 28), cmap='gray')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNey4.png)
I can't find anything wrong, does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The true culprit is the default learning rate used by [`keras.Adadelta`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py#L401) vs [`tf.keras.Adadelta`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.2/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/adadelta.py#L63): `1` vs `1e-4` - see below. It's true that `keras` and `tf.keras` implementations differ a bit, but difference in results can't be as dramatic as you observed (only in a different configuration, e.g. learning rate).

You can confirm this in your original code by running `print(model.optimizer.get_config())`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras

(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test  = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = x_train.reshape((len(x_train), 784))
x_test  = x_test.reshape((len(x_test), 784))  # None, 784

###############################################################################
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(64, input_shape=(784, ), activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(784, activation='sigmoid')
])
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(learning_rate=1),
              loss='binary_crossentropy')

model.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs=10, shuffle=True,
          validation_data=(x_test, x_test))

###############################################################################
temp = model.predict(x_train)
plt.imshow(temp[0].reshape(28, 28), cmap='gray')
```

```py
Epoch 1/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 4s 2ms/step - loss: 0.2229 - val_loss: 0.1668
Epoch 2/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 0.1497 - val_loss: 0.1337
Epoch 3/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 0.1253 - val_loss: 0.1152
Epoch 4/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 0.1103 - val_loss: 0.1033
Epoch 5/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 0.1009 - val_loss: 0.0962
Epoch 6/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0952 - val_loss: 0.0916
Epoch 7/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0914 - val_loss: 0.0885
Epoch 8/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0886 - val_loss: 0.0862
Epoch 9/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0865 - val_loss: 0.0844
Epoch 10/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0849 - val_loss: 0.0830
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use `adam`, the `tf.keras` model performs better. (`keras` and `tf.keras` uses two different version of the optimizers)

Most probably, it has to do with `momentum` for convergence for this data. It is very slow, maybe you'll need to train for more epochs with higher learning rate.

Here's an answer why adadelta should be avoided : [How to set parameters of the Adadelta Algorithm in Tensorflow correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38632536/how-to-set-parameters-of-the-adadelta-algorithm-in-tensorflow-correctly)

```
import tensorflow as tf

(x_train,_), (x_test,_) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.  
x_train = x_train.reshape((len(x_train), 784))  
x_test = x_test.reshape((len(x_test), 784))  # None, 784

# import keras
import tensorflow.keras as keras
my_autoencoder = keras.models.Sequential([
      keras.layers.Dense(64, input_shape=(784, ), activation='relu'),
      keras.layers.Dense(784, activation='sigmoid')                                             
])
my_autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')

my_autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs=10, shuffle=True, validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
```

```
Epoch 1/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 5s 3ms/step - loss: 0.1372 - val_loss: 0.0909
Epoch 2/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 5s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0840 - val_loss: 0.0782
Epoch 3/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 5s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0773 - val_loss: 0.0753
Epoch 4/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 5s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0754 - val_loss: 0.0742
Epoch 5/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 5s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0747 - val_loss: 0.0738
Epoch 6/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 5s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0744 - val_loss: 0.0735
Epoch 7/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 5s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0741 - val_loss: 0.0734
Epoch 8/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 5s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0740 - val_loss: 0.0733
Epoch 9/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 5s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0738 - val_loss: 0.0731
Epoch 10/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 5s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0737 - val_loss: 0.0734

<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f8c83d907b8>
```

N.B: `keras` and `tf.keras` have slightly different implementations for `Model`, so internally they call different functions, the performance can vary, it's no surprise.

In fact, the problem is with the optimizer, not the model, to validate that, you can try training a `keras` model with `tf` AdaDelta, it will also show poor results.

```
import keras
# import tensorflow.keras as keras

my_autoencoder = keras.models.Sequential([
      keras.layers.Dense(64, input_shape=(784, ), activation='relu'),
      keras.layers.Dense(784, activation='sigmoid')                                             
])
my_autoencoder.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adadelta(), loss='binary_crossentropy')

my_autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs=10, shuffle=True, validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
```

```
Train on 60000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 6s 101us/step - loss: 0.6955 - val_loss: 0.6946
Epoch 2/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 6s 99us/step - loss: 0.6936 - val_loss: 0.6927
Epoch 3/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 6s 100us/step - loss: 0.6919 - val_loss: 0.6910
Epoch 4/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 6s 96us/step - loss: 0.6901 - val_loss: 0.6892
Epoch 5/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 6s 94us/step - loss: 0.6883 - val_loss: 0.6873
Epoch 6/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 6s 95us/step - loss: 0.6863 - val_loss: 0.6851
Epoch 7/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 6s 101us/step - loss: 0.6839 - val_loss: 0.6825
Epoch 8/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 6s 101us/step - loss: 0.6812 - val_loss: 0.6794
Epoch 9/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 6s 99us/step - loss: 0.6778 - val_loss: 0.6756
Epoch 10/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 6s 101us/step - loss: 0.6736 - val_loss: 0.6710

<keras.callbacks.callbacks.History at 0x7f8c805bbe10>
```

`keras` and `tf.keras` calls two different optimizers when the optimizer parameter is passed as a string.

```
import tensorflow as tf
# import tensorflow.keras as keras

my_autoencoder = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, input_shape=(784, ), activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(784, activation='sigmoid')                                             
])
my_autoencoder.compile('adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')

my_autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs=1, shuffle=True, validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
my_autoencoder.optimizer
```

`<tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2.adadelta.Adadelta at 0x7f8c7fc3ce80>`

```
import keras
# import tensorflow.keras as keras

my_autoencoder = keras.models.Sequential([
      keras.layers.Dense(64, input_shape=(784, ), activation='relu'),
      keras.layers.Dense(784, activation='sigmoid')                                             
])
my_autoencoder.compile('adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')

my_autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs=1, shuffle=True, validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
my_autoencoder.optimizer
```

`<keras.optimizers.Adadelta at 0x7f8c7fc3c908>`

So, the confusion can be avoided by importing the optimizer separately.

Comment: Wow, thank you, thank you, this has bothered me all day.

Comment: I added some more explanation, just acoid adadelta, adam does the best job in most cases, also use `tf.keras`, it's much better maintained.

Comment: @letterbee Your question is interesting, and this answer is a non-answer, though it's a workaround. Sounds like a bug to report to TensorFlow.

Comment: It's not technically a bug, poor result always doesn't mean bug, recently I found many inconsistencies when reporoducing `keras` and `tf.keras` results. They almost always have different implementations, the issue is with the optimizer, the `tf.keras` model calls a different version of AdaDelta than the `keras` model (when we pass it through as str parameter), if we import the AdaDelta separately you can confirm that.

Comment: The difference shouldn't be this dramatic; there's more at play here.

Comment: Surely, there could be, currently, I'm looking at the source if I can find any major inconsistency.

Comment: I would not say that tf.keras is much better maintained, keras is no longer maintained, and only tf.keras is seeing nwe developments.